# Importing a certificate chain (.crt) in a truststore

Tags: java, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have a chain certificate that includes the machine, ICA and Root CA certificate in one file as server.crt, the format is as follows

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---

ROOT CERT

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---

ICA CERT

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---

MACHINE CERT

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What I'm trying to achieve is import this certificate to Truststore but when I try to do so only the first certificate gets imported and the connection fails.

I tried importing only the machine certificate then the connection was established but while sending data the connection was reset and I got
Error

> sending HTTP Data
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "https://url:443/xyzApi/example/1234561": Connection
>   reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

As a fail check, I used the chain certificate provided and using `curl` I tried to hit a request which works fine as expected without `-k` (without ignoring certificate checks)

NOTE:

- I don't have the Private Key, all I have is the chain certificate which 
  doesn't include any private keys.
- I'm currently using a JKS Keystore.

How to import the certificate chain in JKS or any other Keystore (truststore) formats ?

Comment: why dont you just insert the root's CA certificate? I would insert it into the trustStore no the keystore

Comment: Just to add, 
The SAN and CN of machine cert and url what I'm trying to use matches, so there is no error on that front.

Comment: Split up the file, then import them one by one.

Comment: I have tried splitting up the file and importing them, in that case keytool is not able to establish the link that this is a chain and only proceeds with the machine cert for which the SAN matches and it fails giving me the ResourceAccessException

Comment: @IoannisBarakos sorry for the typo in question, I'm trying to import the same in truststore

Comment: If your chain is correct, it should be enough to add only the Root CA certificate. Try it

Comment: **What 'machine' is this cert for?** If it is for the server you want to connect to, you (the client) don't need the whole chain in the truststore; Java (JSSE using standard trustmanager) will validate a server if _any_ cert in its chain is in the local truststore. (This may not be true for other software.) If it is to identify _you_ the client to the server -- i.e. client auth, also called 2-way or mutual auth -- you _must_ have the privatekey as well as the cert chain in your _keystore_ (_not_ truststore); no manipulation or contortion of the cert(s) without the privatekey will work.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085    It is a 1-way ssl, in which we (client) is verifying the server. The machine cert is the certificate of the server machine.

Comment: Then as I said you only need one cert of the server chain in your truststore. The exception you posted does NOT indicate a problem validating the server cert; it is something else. If you want to fix it, you should investigate the actual problem, To do so you could try running with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and capture the output and look at it or post it, probably as a new Q, since it will be entirely different from what you asked here.

Comment: the issue was resolved, it was due to wrong certificates being shared. 
Thanks all.